# creating objects in for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, object, loops, for-loop

I hope you can help me with this hopefully stupid problem.
I try to do the following:

- creating array with data
- looping through this array within a for loop (based on array.length)
- create new object based on data in array

So far I got the following:

- create array
- loop through array
- create one object based on my constructor

The problem is, the array has a length of 4 and should therefore create 4 objects but it creates only one. If I remove the creation of the object and just log "i' it works, but in the original intention it ends after the first
The loop looks as follows:

```
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
        newObj[i]=new ObjectName(array[i].param1,array[i].param2,array[i].param3)
        }
```

I have no idea why it ends after the first run and I also don't get an error displayed when looking into firebug.

Cheers

Comment: Please make a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ with an example to help clarify.

Comment: This should work. Please show us both your "array" variable, the "newObj" initialisation and eventually the constructor code. Are any exceptions thrown?

Comment: Sorry, it is not the loop it is the object.
During the creation of the object I have a function to calculate the area of a svg path. When running without the calculate area I get all objects (but no area ;) ) if running with the calculate area function I get the area of 1 object but the other objects are not created. Strange thing I really don't understand. Therefore it needs to be this function.
I will create a fiddle to get thiss visualized and will open a new topic since it is not the loop.... I will post the code as soon as I'm allowed to post an answer to this question (6 houre to got)

Answer (score 0):

Does changing the

`newObj[i] =`

to

`newObj.push(...)`

help?

Also how is newObj initialized?

`newObj = []`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < (stringNums.length); i++) {             
    Dictionary[stringNums[i]] =  stringNums[i].length;
}
```

Comment: "stringNums" is an Array; "Dictionary" is an Object